# Group_by and mutate slow on large dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, tidyverse

I am working with large (min 8 mil rows) `dataframes` and want to do some basic calculations based on a couple grouping variables and `rmultinom`. As my code stands it takes at least ~1 sec to complete the calculation, which wouldn't be a problem but I need to do it thousands of times so I would really like to speed this up.

I am currently using `dataframes` and `tidyverse` but I am not tied to either of these. I have tried to implement using `data.table` but couldn't figure it out. Any suggestions of how I could speed things up would be much appreciated.

An example (the real data can be an order of magnitude larger or more):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)

# create dummy data
df <- data.frame(fact = rep(letters, each = 312000), 
                 month = rep(month.name, 26), 
                 num = rep(sample(10000:100000, 12), 26), 
                 prob = runif(312))

# Order by month     
df <- df[order(df$month), ]

# group by two factor variables and calculate new variable 
microbenchmark({
  df2 <- df %>%
    group_by(fact, month) %>%
    mutate(res = ifelse(prob > 0, c(rmultinom(1, num[1], prob = prob)), 0))}, times = 10)


 > Unit: milliseconds
 > min      lq       mean     median   uq        max         neval
 > 816.3126 822.4083 840.7966 834.6163 855.5139  879.9345    10
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit too long for a comment, so I post it here.

Running

```
library(profr)
plot(profr(
df %>% group_by(fact, month) %>% 
   mutate(res = ifelse(prob > 0, c(rmultinom(1, num[1], prob = prob)), 0))
))
```

I get the following:

[image]

So, it looks like you really want to find a faster implementation for `multinom`, which seems to be the bottleneck. This bottleneck is the same for both `dplyr` and `data.table`, which means only speeding up `rmultinorm` will give you substantial speed improvements.

Comment: OK thanks, after further investigation another user had the same problem with `rmultinom` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097269/efficient-multinomial-sampling-when-sample-size-and-probability-vary), they implemented a solution using `Rcpp` which I haven't used but will look into.

Answer (score 2):

You might as well reduce the overhead caused by the pipe operator, in both `dplyr` and `DT` syntax.

To illustrate the overhead caused by pipes:

```
microbenchmark(pipe = iris %>%
                 group_by(Species) %>% 
                 mutate(mean = mean(Sepal.Length)),
               no_pipe = mutate(group_by(iris, Species), mean = mean(Sepal.Length)),
               times = 100) %>% autoplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table), you could do:

```
dt <- copy(df)
setDT(dt)

dt[, res := 0L][prob > 0, res := c(rmultinom(1, num[1], prob = prob)), by = .(fact, month)]
```

Which gives you a minor speed improvement:

```
microbenchmark(dp = df %>%
                 group_by(fact, month) %>%
                 mutate(res = ifelse(prob > 0, c(rmultinom(1, num[1], prob = prob)), 0)),
               dt = dt[, res := 0L][prob > 0, res := c(rmultinom(1, num[1], prob = prob)), by = .(fact, month)],
               times = 1)
```

> ```
> Unit: seconds
>  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
>    dp 1.356745 1.356745 1.356745 1.356745 1.356745 1.356745     1
>    dt 1.063363 1.063363 1.063363 1.063363 1.063363 1.063363     1
> ```

Comment: @Jaap Thank you, it all adds up! Do you think I would be able to make further substantial improvements or is this likely about as good as I'll get? Need to decide if I keep looking for improvements or just move on. Cheers.

Comment: hmm I just ran your code on my machine and I didn't get any performance gain at all.