# How to avoid loops in outcome generator

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have a data frame with probabilities for three outcomes: A, B and C. Their probabilities are prob1, prob2, and prob3:

```
df = data.frame(prob1=runif(1000,0,0.2),prob2=runif(1000,0,0.1))
df$prob3 = 1-df$prob1-df$prob2
```

I am trying to simulate an outcome for each row given its unique probabilities and run the following loop:

```
df$outcome = NA
for (i in 1:1000) {
   df$outcome[i]<-sample(c(A,B,C), 1, prob = c(df$prob1[i],df$prob2[i],df$prob3[i]), replace = FALSE)
}
```

I have a large data set and would like to avoid loops. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way via multinomial sampling:

```
m <- t(apply(df,1,rmultinom,n=1,size=1))  ## 1000 x 3 matrix of 0/1 values
w <- apply(m,1,which)                     ## vector of 1000 values in {1,2,3}
```

If you want labels you could follow this with `c("A","B","C")[w]`.

If you want to go beyond base R, the `Hmisc` package has `rMultinom`:

```
library(Hmisc)
colnames(df) <- c("A","B","C")
w <- rMultinom(df, m=1)
```

I modified the column names because `rMultinom` automatically uses the column names as the values of the samples.

If you need *really fast* vectorized multinomial sampling and you're willing to deal with the hassle of compiled code, the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097269/efficient-multinomial-sampling-when-sample-size-and-probability-vary) can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` :

```
df$outcome <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sample(c(A, B, C), 1, prob = x))
```

Or using `dplyr` `rowwise` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(outcome = sample(c(A,B, C), 1, prob = c_across()))
```